# Saving function output to specific place in dataframe

Tags: r

I'm working on a function that predicts using a gbm model, one row at a time. Then, I want to save the predicted value in a specific place in my DF so that the next value can be predicted with that output included. Basically, a prediction with a lagged dependent variable. Below is a snippet of my data

```
   DEC    AAA_CCC BBBB LLLLL DDD_SHR ST_DSC WKG.P WKG.P.1T       _CHNG   XXXX_pr   XXXX_pr_r XXXX_vol      XXXX_.T.1.
38   0      0.99    0    0     0.51   8.28     0        0         6.04     2.84       2.84     10.49            9.83
39   0      0.99    0    0     0.51   8.27     0        0         5.97     2.75       2.75     10.33           10.49
40   0      1.04    0    0     0.51   8.27     0        0         6.01     2.81       2.81     10.58           10.33
41   0      0.98    0    0     0.51   8.28     0        0         5.99     2.87       2.87      9.49           10.58
42   0      0.98    0    1     0.52   8.27     0        0         6.10     2.81       2.81     10.35            9.49
43   0      0.95    0    1     0.51   8.27     0        0         6.01     2.72       2.71     10.67           10.35
    XXXX_wd  XXXX_ICP_A  XXXX_ICP_A_.T.1.
38     4.41        0              1
39     4.33        1              0
40     4.36        0              1
41     4.32        1              0
42     4.19        0              1
43     4.25        1              0
```

This function needs to: find columns with specific names within a DF, check if there are 0s inside, if yes - predict a value based on the row with a 0 in it. Then, save the predicted value in that 0 place, and in a different column with a 0. Keep repeating that until there are no more 0s in the 'vol' column.

I've come up with this:

```
PREDICTION<-function (a, model)
{ 
vol<-select(a, ends_with("vol"))
vol_1<-select(a, ends_with("vol_.T.1."))
while (min(which(a[,colnames(vol)]== 0))!=0) {
PRED<-predict(model, a[min(which(a[,colnames(vol)]== 0)),])
a[[min(which(a[,colnames(vol_1)]== 0)),colnames(vol_1)]]<<-print(PRED)
a[[min(which(a[,colnames(vol)]== 0)),colnames(vol)]]<<-print(PRED)

}}
```

It prints the right values but doesn't save them the way I wanted. So the while part also doesn't work - values are not saved properly so it loops over the same row forever. I've tried replacing the print with return which didn't change anything. I don't really know where to go from here so I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution - definitely not elegant I will work on improving it. Posting if anyone is interesed.

I simplified the loop withing my function - for instead of while. The rows I'm working on are always in the same range so this helped even visually make the code easier to look at. I will be messing with this more so that might make a comeback to make the code more universal.

```
PREDICTION <- function(a, model)
{
  vol <- select(a, ends_with("vol"))
  vol_1 <- select(a, ends_with("vol_.T.1."))
  for (i in 54:72) {
a[[i,colnames(vol)]] <- print(predict(model, a[i,]))
a[[i+1,colnames(vol_1)]] <- print(predict(model, a[i,]))
  }
  return(a)
  }
```

Then I use `mapply` to map this function over my DF which contains dataframes and models to use.

```
LISTA$DF <- mapply(PREDICTION, a=LISTA$DF, model = LISTA$GBM)
```

Essentially this was mostly a syntax problem on my end. Just goes to show how much more I have to learn to be able to code more efficiently and functionally.